# Which method HTTP GET/POST used by AJAX requests?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee

Which method  HTTP GET/POST used by AJAX requests? 
 And can we specify the method while making Ajax call?

Comment: Both and yes we can: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest specifically the open method

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory - no, it's "yes we can" :)

Comment: Yes, you can specify the method but the way you set that up will depend on the way you are issuing the request. For example, are you using jQuery  or just regular javascript?

Comment: jQuery (and YUI, Mootools, Prototype, and [many other libraries](http://microjs.com/)) are regular JavaScript, they just happen to be already written by other people so you don't have to reinvent wheels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which method HTTP GET/POST used by AJAX requests?

Either. Follow the normal rules for deciding which is appropriate. (i.e. GET is repeatable, POST changes stuff, etc). If you are using XHR, most browsers will let you use any of [the HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), not just GET and POST.

> And can we specify the method while making Ajax call?

Yes. Well. Usually. Ajax just means "Making an HTTP request and reading the response without leaving the current page"; there are lots of different ways to do that. XHR lets you specify the method, JSON-P doesn't, submitting a form to a hidden iframe does, dynamically adding an image to the page doesn't, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Which method HTTP GET/POST used by AJAX requests?

Both are used, based on programmer.

> And can we specify the method while making Ajax call?

Yes you can. It is, however based on method you're sending your ajax

Comment: It is only based on the programmer if the programmer isn't a good programmer. It should be based on the nature of the request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both - depends on what you want to do. GET is used for retrieving data without side-effects. There are also other methods you can use, such as DELETE and PUT.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both GET or POST. Those are one of the HTTP methods that are supported by web browsers and either you can use it through AJAX or the conventional way.

Answer (score 1):

This code should help you get started:

```
var params={
    type: "POST",   //you can make this GET
    url: "./ajax/addFriend.php",
    data: "friend="+friend,
    success: function(msg){
      alert('Friend added successfully');
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
    }
  };
  var result=$.ajax(params).responseText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify the method while making a call. For example, using jquery you can use the call the method type parameter:

> "The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". 
>   Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE,  can also be
>   used here, but they are not supported by all browsers."

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "test.js",
   dataType: "script"
 });

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls can be made with either GET or POST...you decide...

There are a couple ways you can do it...Pure JavaScript using the `XMLHttpRequest` object, or with an AJAX framework such as jQuery.

**Pure JavaScript Example**

```
//Create an instance
req = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Use the open command to open the connection...note the username and password
//are used as needed and are not required
//open( Method, URL, Asynchronous, UserName, Password )
req.open('GET','/path/to/send/request',true);  //Could also use POST

//Set a callback to handle the request response
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //Common practice to check the ready state and handle it appropriately
    //ready state === 4 is for success
    if(req.readyState === 4) {
        //Do stuff...
    }
}

//Now make the request using the send call
//send( Data )
req.send(null);
```

There are other useful events and options for the XMLHttpRequest Object.  And there is an API for interacting with the response as well.  The documentation can be found at **[this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)**

Now using an AJAX framework is also possible, and can make things much simpler.  jQuery is my personal preference in frameworks.

**jQuery Example**

```
//Here we use jQuery framework to make the call
//With jQuery, you set the options and supply a call back
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",                       //type GET/POST/ETC
    url: "some.php",                    //URL to send to
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",  //data you want to send
    success: function(msg){             //Callback when request is a success
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
//Could also do a 'GET' request
```

The jQuery AJAX documentation can be found **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Using an AJAX Framework, such as jQuery, will simplify your API calls, making it nicer to read and less code to write.  The downsides are that you gain the overhead of the libraries (performance and control space size).

If you plan to use the framework throughout your site (for AJAX calls and DOM manipulation), then I'd use jQuery, but if it is for one or two calls, just use the XMLHttpRequest calls, as the overhead will not be worth it.

Comment: I think jQuery is going to deprecate the success callback in favor of the done promise/defer.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into it.